# Get title based on relationship (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, relationship, laravel-blade

So I have the following taxonomy:

- School
- Department
- Class

A school `hasMany` departments. A department `hasMany` classes.

A department `belongsTo` a school. A class `belongsTo` a department and a school.

A school, department, or a class can have a test assigned to it. This is determined via pivot tables like so:

- school_test
- department_test
- class_test

This all works absolutely perfectly, but on a test page, I want to be able to display the following info:

`School Name | Department Name | Class Name`

If it's school-wide then it should just show the school name.

If it's department-wide then it should show: `School Name | Department Name`.

And if it's for a class then it should show: `School Name | Department Name | Class Name`.

My blade code looks like this:

```
{{$test->school->first()->name}}
        @if($test->department->isNotEmpty())
            &nbsp; | &nbsp;
            {{$test->department->first()->name}}
        @if($test->class->isNotEmpty())
            &nbsp; | &nbsp;
            {{$test->class->first()->name}}
        @endif
        @endif
```

This works fine for when it's a school-wide test but it will break when I'm trying to load up a test for a class as it obviously doesn't have a relationship to a department via the pivot tables. Instead I would need to do something like this:

```
{{$test->class->first()->department->school->name}}
```

That traverses the relationships, but how do I incorporate this neatly in my view to account for the different scenarios?

All help welcome!

Comment: why you are querying in your view?? each line making a new query which is not good, right??

Comment: Hey @Sohel0415 - fair point. This is mostly just for me to test quickly. I'll refactor it to a model method at some point.

Comment: update your question with controller code, relationship function in models

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get all the tests `$tests = Test::all()` (or add query scopes if needed)

Loop through each test using `@foreach($tests as $test)`

Add relationships to the `Test` model class for School, Department, Class

```
function school() {
    $this->belongsTo(School::class);
}
```

Create a helper function to determine what the Test directly belongs to

```
function isFor($parent) {
    switch($parent) {
        case 'school':
            return $this->school;

        case 'department':
            return $this->department;

        case 'class':
            return $this->class;
    }
}
```

Then you can use that in your view to check what the test directly belongs to

```
@if($test->isFor('school'))
```

If you don't want to `switch/case` then use `if/elseif` to do something like

```
function isFor() {
    if($this->school) {
        return 'school';
    }        
    elseif($this->department) {
        return 'department';
    }
    elseif($this->class) {
        return 'class';
    }
}
```

And then in the view something like:

```
@if($test->isFor() == 'school')
```

Once you determine what the direct parent is you can carry on accessing the names directly from the parent, instead of having to go through another relationship so:

```
@if($test->isFor('department'))

{{ $test->department->name }}
```

I'd also advise creating different partials/views for each different view

```
@if($test->isFor('department'))
    @include('partials.test-department')
@endif
```

And put exactly what that view should contain in that partial

Answer (score 1):

To get school by its test ID:

```
School::whereHas('tests', function($q) use($testId) {
    $q->where('id', $testId);
})->first();
```

`tests` here is many-to-many relationship.

The same way you can get department and class.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful but it's grabbing all the classes that belong to a department. I want to be able to get the specific class that the test is assigned to for example.

Comment: @roo I'm sorry but I don't get the question then. If you want to get only some classes, use constraints. If you want to get just one class, please describe what exactly are criteria.

Comment: to clarify: I want to load up a specific test and see which school | department | class that it is assigned to.

Comment: Thanks, that was very useful! I ended up going with another answer but this was valid too :)